# Unable to Install GlassdoorItem

Tags: python, scrapy

conda install -c auto glassdoor
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- glassdoor

Answer (score 0):

If you use Windows, try this.

Command Promport → 
Input [**conda config --append channels conda-forge**]

You can direct conda to locate the channel directly through this operation.